# A question about OpenOCD

Tags: arm

I believe what I am asking is extremely specific, but keeping hope that I might get some direction

I have used a clone ST- Link v2 programmer to download code into a NRF51822 Cortex M0 SOC from Nordic. In short, I have been following this guide here

http://icarus-sensors.github.io/general/starting-with-nRF51822.html

When I try to erase the flash of the chip using OpenOCD as said in the guide, I encounter this error

When I execute

nrf51 mass_erase
The terminal says
Unknown device (HWID 0x00000057)

Is this that the NRF51822 device is not recognised on the STLink is not recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source](http://sourceforge.net/p/openocd/code/ci/master/tree/src/flash/nor/nrf51.c) it appears that HWID 0x00000057 is not supported.  See the nrf51_known_devices_table from line 143 onwards.

Worth asking about this on the OpenOCD [forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/openocd/mailman/openocd-devel/?viewmonth=201507&style=threaded) there.